# Extraction Operator overloading while using a pointer from another Class name

Tags: c++, oop, extraction-operator

In my assignment, it states the program must have/do this:

*Define a Fraction class with num and den as its private data. Include a constructor to initialize the fraction to 0/1, a copy constructor, a destructor, and overloading functions to overload the assignment operator as well as friend functions (non-member) to overload << and >> to output and input a fraction*

*Define a class called FracList with private members fracPtr, a Fraction pointer and size to hold the size of the array of Fraction objects.*

*In main, create two FracList objects, ask the user how many elements to allocate for each list, read as many Fraction objects from the keyboard as specified by the user into each (using >> operator).*

**Example of how this part of the program should run**

Enter number of Fractions for list 1: 3

Enter number of Fractions for list 2: 4

Enter 3 Fractions for list 1:  2/5 4/3 5/7

Enter 4 Fractions for list 2: 5/8 5/4 3/8 4/9

The part in main is where I am running into problems, because in the FracList class, we are using a pointer that is part of the Fraction class, causing much confusion with the extraction operators for me.

The issue I am coming across has to do with the last part of the code in main, which may very well be caused by other errors elsewhere. fracPtr is a private pointer in the class FracList. However, it is called/initialized as Fraction *fracPtr. I would think because of this, it would reference the Fraction class >> operator when I input list1.fracPtr[i] and allow the user to enter fractions (as the Fraction class >> operator is set to do).

Here is the relevant code from my program.

**From the Fraction class**
(.cpp)

```
istream& operator>> (istream& in, Fraction& f)
{
    char slash;
    in >> f.den >> slash >> f.num;
    f.reduce();
    return in;
}

Fraction Fraction::get_reduce()
{
    this->reduce();
    return *this;
}

void Fraction::reduce()
{
    if (num == den)
        num = den = 1;
    else
        for (int i = num; i > 1; i++)
        if (num % i == 0 && den % i == 0)
    {
        num /= i;
        den /= i;
    }
}
```

(.h)

```
friend istream& operator>>(istream& in, Fraction& f);
public:
Fraction(int = 0, int = 1);
private:
int num, den;
void reduce();
```

**From the FracList class**

(.cpp)

```
istream& operator >> (istream& in, const FracList& List)
{
for (int i = 0; i < List.size; i++)
in >> List.fracPtr[i];
return in;
}

void FracList::set_ptr(Fraction* p)
{
Fraction* fracPtr = p;
}

Fraction* FracList::get_ptr()
{
return fracPtr;
}

// Default Constructor

FracList::FracList(int s)
{
size = s;
fracPtr = new Fraction[size];
}

FracList::FracList(const FracList& List)
{
size = List.size;
fracPtr = new Fraction[size];
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    fracPtr[i] == List[i];
}

int FracList::get_size() const
{
return size;
}

FracList& FracList::operator=(const FracList& List)
{
if (*this != List)
{
    delete [] fracPtr;
    size = List.size;
    fracPtr = new Fraction[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        fracPtr[i] = List[i];
}
return *this;
}
```

(.h)

```
friend istream& operator >> (istream& in, const FracList& List);

public:
int get_size() const;
FracList& operator=(const FracList& List);
void set_ptr(Fraction* p);
Fraction* get_ptr();
FracList(int size = 0);
FracList(const FracList& List)

private:
int size;
Fraction *fracPtr;
```

(main)

```
int main()
{
int size1;
int size2;
FracList list1;
FracList list2;
//Fraction* obj;

cout << "Enter number of Fractions for list1: ";
cin >> size1;

cout << "Enter number of Fractions for list2: ";
cin >> size2;

size1 = list1.get_size();
size2 = list2.get_size();

for (int i = 0; i < size1; i++)
cout << "Enter " << size1 << "Fractions for list1: ";
cin >> list1.fracPtr[i];

}
```

Comment: Please read up on how to create a [mcve], as well as [ask] and [tour]. Also, the line `Fraction* fracPtr = p;` in `set_ptr` creates a new variable and assigns the pointer to it, and the new variable immediately goes out of scope; it does not affect any value in the class, and so does nothing

Comment: I read both of those before making this post. I wanted to ensure all relevant details were included which is why this question is somewhat long.

Hmm, perhaps the set_ptr function is the issue here? Wouldn't the info from set_ptr be passed to get_ptr as it is, thus returning the pointer? Is the set_ptr function even necessary?

Comment: You haven't understood what the other guy wrote. You declare a new variable here, `fracPtr`. This variable has the same name as a member of your class, but this does not mean that it is that member, it means that it overshadows it. Simply write `fracPtr = p;` instead of `Fraction* fracPtr = p;` and you solve that issue (not sure if there are others).

Comment: By the way, handling a raw array that is degenerated to a pointer is pretty much C-style, not usual C++-style. Has a lot of drawbacks, like in this case, the hassle you are in just right now. Use a proper container class, like `std::vector`, although in your case, it might be that the wording of your assignment prevents that.

Comment: A general thing, why the other guy told you to read the tour: You haven't asked a question. Do it like "I want to do this and that in general, and here I have this testing example which should result in this output but instead does this". Right now, you say that you ran into confusion, but not that something does not work. From our point of view, your code might be fine and you are just confused, which is nothing one can answer to. If you want to make working code better, consider posting it on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thank you for the replies along with the advice for future posting, Aziuth. My assignment does not allow using std::vector as we have not gotten to that point in the class yet.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the answer to the problem and will post the answer for reference to future readers.

The code should look like this (in main)

```
int size1 = 0; // Declare size variables as ints
int size2 = 0;
//int index = -1;

//Fraction obj;


cout << "Enter number of Fractions for list1: ";
cin >> size1; // Get the size of list 1

cout << "Enter number of Fractions for list2: ";
cin >> size2; // Get the size of list 2


FracList list1(size1); // Pass each size into its list object (can use as array)
FracList list2(size2);

size1 = list1.get_size(); // set the sizes equal to the size private variable
size2 = list2.get_size();

cout << "Enter " << size1 << " Fractions for list1: ";
for (int i = 0; i < size1; i++)
cin >> list1[i]; // Calls the operator to enter fractions

cout << "Enter " << size2 << " Fractions for list2: ";
for (int i = 0; i < size2; i++)
cin >> list2[i]; // Calls the operator to enter fractions
```